# Rigid body isn't working properly - pretzel doesn't get dropped into a jar

Tags: rigidbody

I'm trying to drop a pretzel into my jar using rigid body but for some reasons the pretzel would bounce off before reaching the opening of the jar.

Pretzel would bounce off here instead of falling into the jar.

[image]

Here is the rigid body setting for both objects.

Jar setting:

[image]

Pretzel setting before I baked the physic:

[image]

I have also checked the list of things this [blender forum](https://blenderartists.org/t/rigid-body-doesnt-work-and-object-is-not-falling-on-another-one/1366371) suggested but still doesn't work. Anyone knows what's going on?

My Blender File:
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I just included it in my post. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Apply the scale of your 3 objects (cube, jar and bretzel)
- Remove the invisible cone
- Close the bretzel action in the *Dope Sheet* in *Action Editor* mode
- Lower the *Sensitivity Margin* of the jar down to 0,01
- Enable the *Sensitivity > Collision Margin* of the bretzel and set it to 0,01

[image]

Comment: That solved it but my pretzel is really bouncy when dropped into the jar. How were you able to get the pretzel to stay down like that?

Comment: I got it. Within the Dope Sheet, I deleted the keyframes that made it the pretzel jumpy.